# vmware player not able to open with kernel 4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64 on fedora

Tags: linux-kernel, fedora, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am not able to open vmware player after updating the kernel to 4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64 on fedora 22

I am able to open vmplayer or vmware workstation with the old kernel

when i open vmplayer i am geting this message

```
vmware kernel  module updater

Before you run  vmware, several  modules must be compiled  and loaded  into the running kernel
```

when i try to install to install it says

```
unable to start services
```

if some has already faced this problem and has a fix please post

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: thanks for that.. but unfortunately it didn't work.it has shown this error M1QeIn/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-M1QeIn/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
Makefile:1389: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-M1QeIn/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-M1QeIn/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/4.4.14-200.fc22.x86_64+debug'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-M1QeIn/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

Comment: @ltps paste it on fpaste.com

Comment: thanks for the link.. can you please tell me under which directory i have to paste the code

Comment: @ltps Actually the fixes are quite specific to the vmware and kernel version. Unfortunately, you will have to google for the errors now. :(